# What happens if a defender explodes the hatch the defuser is on?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

If the attackers plant the defuser on a breachable hatch and then an attacker explodes the hatch, the defuser get's destroyed and the attackers lose. But if a defender is the one to destroy the hatch do the defenders lose or do the attackers still lose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

Indeed, the attackers still lose since the defuser is destroyed this way.

Comment: Is the defuser actually destroyed or attackers lose because the defuser leaves the bomb site?